# LocationManager minDistance

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

My sample code:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 50.0f, this);

 . . .

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

    System.out.println(loc.getLatitude()+ " - " + loc.getLongitude());        
}
```

my **minDistance** parameter set to 50.0f (50 metres)

but **onLocationChanged** called many times even if I dont move phone at all.

As I found from docs:

> The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of
>   location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider
>   will only send your application an update when the location has
>   changed by at least minDistance meters.

so my question is why location changed ?

Comment: What is your android version? Docs says: Prior to Jellybean, the minTime parameter was only a hint, and some location provider implementations ignored it. From Jellybean and onwards it is mandatory for Android compatible devices to observe both the minTime and minDistance parameters.

Comment: @greywolf82, Android 4.3 (Galaxy S3). I know about minTime  parametr. But my issue with minDistance and minTime not important at all. Thank you for response.

Comment: Maybe you are seeing this behavior because the gps can't get a fix, wait for satellite fixes and then check if the interval is ok.